# Wifi drops out randomly on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, 18.04, wireless, internet

I'm currently using Ubuntu 18.04. Everytime I use my laptop, at any time the Wifi just switches off and I'm forced to use a wired connection instead. These are the errors:

```
[ 6647.651100] ath: phy1: Failed to wakeup in 500us
[ 6647.936859] ath: phy1: RX failed to go idle in 10 ms RXSM=0xffffffff
[ 6647.954538] ath: phy1: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0xffffffff AR_DIAG_SW=0xffffffff DMADBG_7=0xffffffff
[ 6652.514970] ath: phy1: Failed to wakeup in 500us
[ 6652.795903] ath: phy1: RX failed to go idle in 10 ms RXSM=0xffffffff
[ 6652.813576] ath: phy1: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0xffffffff AR_DIAG_SW=0xffffffff DMADBG_7=0xffffffff
```

So what could be the issue? I've had a look online but some of the articles are old. I have a QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter by Quaalcomm.

EDIT:

```
Aug 15 14:22:33 ashaz-Aspire-E1-572 NetworkManager[881]: <info>  [1597497753.6670] NetworkManager (version 1.20.4) is starting... (for the first time)
Aug 15 14:22:33 ashaz-Aspire-E1-572 NetworkManager[881]: <info>  [1597497753.6671] Read config: /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf (lib: 10-dns-resolved.conf, 20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf, no-mac-addr
Aug 15 14:22:33 ashaz-Aspire-E1-572 NetworkManager[881]: <warn>  [1597497753.6671] config: unknown key 'wifi.cloned-mac-address' in section [device-mac-addr-change-wifi] of file '/usr/lib/NetworkManager/c
Aug 15 14:22:33 ashaz-Aspire-E1-572 NetworkManager[881]: <warn>  [1597497753.6671] config: unknown key 'ethernet.cloned-mac-address' in section [device-mac-addr-change-wifi] of file '/usr/lib/NetworkManag
Aug 15 14:22:33 ashaz-Aspire-E1-572 NetworkManager[881]: <info>  [1597497753.8662] bus-manager: acquired D-Bus service "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
Aug 15 14:22:34 ashaz-Aspire-E1-572 NetworkManager[881]: <info>  [1597497754.2556] manager[0x55858dc96020]: monitoring kernel firmware directory '/lib/firmware'.
Aug 15 14:22:34 ashaz-Aspire-E1-572 NetworkManager[881]: <info>  [1597497754.2557] monitoring ifupdown state file '/run/network/ifstate'.
Aug 15 14:22:34 ashaz-Aspire-E1-572 NetworkManager[881]: <info>  [1597497754.2631] hostname: hostname: using hostnamed
Aug 15 14:22:34 ashaz-Aspire-E1-572 NetworkManager[881]: <info>  [1597497754.2632] hostname: hostname changed from (none) to "ashaz-Aspire-E1-572"
Aug 15 14:22:34 ashaz-Aspire-E1-572 NetworkManager[881]: <info>  [1597497754.2646] dns-mgr[0x55858dc7e290]: init: dns=systemd-resolved rc-manager=symlink, plugin=systemd-resolved
Aug 15 14:22:34 ashaz-Aspire-E1-572 NetworkManager[881]: <info>  [1597497754.2654] manager[0x55858dc96020]: rfkill: Wi-Fi hardware radio set enabled
Aug 15 14:22:34 ashaz-Aspire-E1-572 NetworkManager[881]: <info>  [1597497754.2654] manager[0x55858dc96020]: rfkill: WWAN hardware radio set enabled
Aug 15 14:22:35 ashaz-Aspire-E1-572 NetworkManager[881]: <info>  [1597497755.1398] Loaded device plugin: NMWifiFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.20.4/libnm-device-plugin-wifi.so)
Aug 15 14:22:35 ashaz-Aspire-E1-572 NetworkManager[881]: <info>  [1597497755.7300] Loaded device plugin: NMTeamFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.20.4/libnm-device-plugin-team.so)
Aug 15 14:22:36 ashaz-Aspire-E1-572 NetworkManager[881]: <info>  [1597497756.6219] Loaded device plugin: NMBluezManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.20.4/libnm-device-plugin-bluetooth.so)
Aug 15 14:22:36 ashaz-Aspire-E1-572 NetworkManager[881]: <info>  [1597497756.6266] Loaded device plugin: NMAtmManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.20.4/libnm-device-plugin-adsl.so)
Aug 15 14:22:36 ashaz-Aspire-E1-572 NetworkManager[881]: <info>  [1597497756.6689] Loaded device plugin: NMWwanFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.20.4/libnm-device-plugin-wwan.so)
Aug 15 14:22:36 ashaz-Aspire-E1-572 NetworkManager[881]: <info>  [1597497756.6691] manager: rfkill: Wi-Fi enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Aug 15 14:22:36 ashaz-Aspire-E1-572 NetworkManager[881]: <info>  [1597497756.6692] manager: rfkill: WWAN enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Aug 15 14:22:36 ashaz-Aspire-E1-572 NetworkManager[881]: <info>  [1597497756.6694] manager: Networking is enabled by state file
Aug 15 14:22:36 ashaz-Aspire-E1-572 NetworkManager[881]: <info>  [1597497756.6695] dhcp-init: Using DHCP client 'internal'
Aug 15 14:22:37 ashaz-Aspire-E1-572 NetworkManager[881]: <info>  [1597497757.2471] settings: Loaded settings plugin: ifupdown ("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.20.4/libnm-settings-plugin-ifupdo
Aug 15 14:22:37 ashaz-Aspire-E1-572 NetworkManager[881]: <info>  [1597497757.2472] settings: Loaded settings plugin: keyfile (internal)
Aug 15 14:22:37 ashaz-Aspire-E1-572 NetworkManager[881]: <info>  [1597497757.2472] ifupdown: management mode: unmanaged
Aug 15 14:22:37 ashaz-Aspire-E1-572 NetworkManager[881]: <warn>  [1597497757.3983] ifupdown: interfaces file /etc/network/interfaces doesn't exist
Aug 15 14:22:38 ashaz-Aspire-E1-572 NetworkManager[881]: <info>  [1597497758.1289] device (lo): carrier: link connected
Aug 15 14:22:38 ashaz-Aspire-E1-572 NetworkManager[881]: <info>  [1597497758.1294] manager: (lo): new Generic device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/1)
Aug 15 14:22:38 ashaz-Aspire-E1-572 NetworkManager[881]: <info>  [1597497758.1313] manager: (enp1s0f0): new Ethernet device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2)
Aug 15 14:22:38 ashaz-Aspire-E1-572 NetworkManager[881]: <info>  [1597497758.1332] device (enp1s0f0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Aug 15 14:22:38 ashaz-Aspire-E1-572 NetworkManager[881]: <warn>  [1597497758.3398] Error: failed to open /run/network/ifstate
Aug 15 14:22:38 ashaz-Aspire-E1-572 NetworkManager[881]: <info>  [1597497758.9038] bluez: use BlueZ version 5
Aug 15 14:22:38 ashaz-Aspire-E1-572 NetworkManager[881]: <info>  [1597497758.9040] modem-manager: ModemManager available
Aug 15 14:22:38 ashaz-Aspire-E1-572 NetworkManager[881]: <info>  [1597497758.9076] bluez5: NAP: added interface 40:F0:2F:B6:DD:25
Aug 15 14:22:44 ashaz-Aspire-E1-572 NetworkManager[881]: <info>  [1597497764.2548] manager: startup complete
Aug 15 14:22:49 ashaz-Aspire-E1-572 NetworkManager[881]: <info>  [1597497769.9121] manager: (anbox0): new Bridge device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3)
Aug 15 14:22:49 ashaz-Aspire-E1-572 NetworkManager[881]: <info>  [1597497769.9187] device (anbox0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Aug 15 14:22:49 ashaz-Aspire-E1-572 NetworkManager[881]: <info>  [1597497769.9235] device (anbox0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Aug 15 14:22:49 ashaz-Aspire-E1-572 NetworkManager[881]: <info>  [1597497769.9249] device (anbox0): Activation: starting connection 'anbox0' (e1ab760e-c80e-459e-bf6e-7cc31feb7293)
Aug 15 14:22:49 ashaz-Aspire-E1-572 NetworkManager[881]: <info>  [1597497769.9257] device (anbox0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Aug 15 14:22:49 ashaz-Aspire-E1-572 NetworkManager[881]: <info>  [1597497769.9266] device (anbox0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Aug 15 14:22:49 ashaz-Aspire-E1-572 NetworkManager[881]: <info>  [1597497769.9270] device (anbox0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Aug 15 14:22:49 ashaz-Aspire-E1-572 NetworkManager[881]: <info>  [1597497769.9274] device (anbox0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Aug 15 14:22:50 ashaz-Aspire-E1-572 NetworkManager[881]: <info>  [1597497770.0774] device (anbox0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Aug 15 14:22:50 ashaz-Aspire-E1-572 NetworkManager[881]: <info>  [1597497770.0782] device (anbox0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Aug 15 14:22:50 ashaz-Aspire-E1-572 NetworkManager[881]: <info>  [1597497770.0793] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Aug 15 14:22:50 ashaz-Aspire-E1-572 NetworkManager[881]: <info>  [1597497770.0824] device (anbox0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Aug 15 14:23:26 ashaz-Aspire-E1-572 NetworkManager[881]: <info>  [1597497806.8524] agent-manager: req[0x55858dd10dd0, :1.334/org.gnome.Shell.NetworkAgent/1000]: agent registered
Aug 15 14:24:00 ashaz-Aspire-E1-572 NetworkManager[881]: <info>  [1597497840.8712] audit: op="radio-control" arg="wwan-enabled" pid=2157 uid=1000 result="success"
Aug 15 14:25:11 ashaz-Aspire-E1-572 NetworkManager[881]: <info>  [1597497911.2875] device (enp1s0f0): carrier: link connected
Aug 15 14:25:11 ashaz-Aspire-E1-572 NetworkManager[881]: <info>  [1597497911.2885] device (enp1s0f0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'carrier-changed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 15 14:25:11 ashaz-Aspire-E1-572 NetworkManager[881]: <info>  [1597497911.2918] policy: auto-activating connection 'Wired connection 1' (885f3d39-5758-3ced-9722-962de94aed55)
Aug 15 14:25:11 ashaz-Aspire-E1-572 NetworkManager[881]: <info>  [1597497911.2940] device (enp1s0f0): Activation: starting connection 'Wired connection 1' (885f3d39-5758-3ced-9722-962de94aed55)
Aug 15 14:25:11 ashaz-Aspire-E1-572 NetworkManager[881]: <info>  [1597497911.2945] device (enp1s0f0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 15 14:25:11 ashaz-Aspire-E1-572 NetworkManager[881]: <info>  [1597497911.2953] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
```

Comment: Read the logs with `sudo journalctl -b 0 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager`

Comment: I added the logs.